# How to change the data types of a column in Pandas when read_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I could not able to change the data types of specific column, I tried using these below codes, but neither works for me.

getting **ValueError: could not convert string to float: '?'**

There were some issues in version supporting of Pandas as I got to know when I searched around.

```
data.Global_intensity = data.Global_intensity.astype(pd.np.float)

data.Global_intensity.apply(float)

data['Global_intensity'] = data['Global_intensity'].astype('float')
```

Here are the versions of modules I am working with.

python: 3.5.2.final.0
pandas: 0.19.0
numpy: 1.11.1

> part of the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 15, 6

data = pd.read_csv('Desktop/household_power_consumptions.csv')
print (data.head())
print ('\n Data Types:')
data['Global_intensity'] = data['Global_intensity'].astype('float')
print (data.dtypes)
```

What I need is to convert the data type of object into float of Global_intensity column to work with matplotlib.pylab library.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please give us some sample data as well? Maybe the issue is inherent in the data.

Comment: Your data contains question marks?

Comment: sure , here it is - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AMFIRNAS/TimeSeriesAnalysis-Pandas/master/TimeSeriesAnalysis/household_power_consumptions.csv

Comment: ooh my bad , just checked . yeah it contains '?' after I did some changes to the dataset.I thought the error not mentioning that , err. I am sorry about this. thanks @cricket_007

Comment: Just fyi `read_csv()` has a `dtype`-parameter among many others: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: thanks @SreejithMenon..